# Can't access user profile in event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssom

I am trying to access a user profile property in a list item event event receiver(item adding).

But I get the following error

> The user could not be found in the database.  You must first create this user by calling CreateUserProfile or GetUserProfile(true).

I have checked the user profile service for the user and the user has a profile in service, I also have checked the profile existence in code using `userProfileManager.UserExists(accountName)` and the profile exist 
 but when I want to access it I get that error

Below is the code

```
SPServiceContext spServiceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite);
UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(spServiceContext);

if (!userProfileManager.UserExists(accountName)) return string.Empty;

UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(false);
var retrunValue = userProfile[strKey].Value ?? string.Empty;

return retrunValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you please add the sample account name that you are using so that we can know the format. It has to be the login name of the user in the format domain\\userName

Comment: oh i see , let me check it , i think i should change userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(false) to userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);

Answer (score 2):

I had to change

```
UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(false);
```

to

```
UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
```

because sharepoint evener receiver doesn't run under the user who has caused the event.

it runs with another user, I don't know what user exactly, maybe spfarmadmin. 
so userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName) will not return profile of a person who has created the item .

below is the  complete code

```
SPServiceContext spServiceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite);
UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(spServiceContext);

if (!userProfileManager.UserExists(accountName)) return string.Empty;

UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
var retrunValue = userProfile[strKey].Value ?? string.Empty;

return retrunValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The login name of the user has to be in the format `domain\userName`.

Also see the below sample code :

```
if (upm.UserExists(loginUserName))
{
    UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(loginUserName);
    //Remaining Logic
}
```

The `loginUserName` should be of the format `domain\userName` in the if block

[User Profile Reference](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/how-to-work-with-user-profiles-and-organization-profiles-by-using-the-server-obj)

[image]